# How to add a time countdown that looks like the default Android clock app in AOD mode by react-native?

Tags: android, typescript, react-native, clock, always-on-display

I'm going to create a Pomodoro timer app but I want my time countdown display in AOD mode to look like the default Android clock app.

I will use react-native to create this app but I can't find any docs to do this. Can I do this?

Comment: So, what's the issue? what is your question? Are you having some errors somewhere?

Comment: There is no single "default Android clock app". Different devices will have different pre-installed clock apps, based on choices made by the device manufacturer.